# RuntimeError: error checking inheritance of module 'datetime'

Tags: python, fastapi, python-datetime

I am getting following error when trying to run my python app:

> RuntimeError: error checking inheritance of <module 'datetime' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/datetime.py'> (type: module)

This is my code:

```py
import datetime
from pydantic.types import Optional
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field

class BlogBase(SQLModel): 
    title: str
    published_at: datetime
    # author:str = Field(default=None, foreign_key="author.id")
    body: str
    updated_at: Optional[str]

class Blog(BlogBase, table=True): 
    id: int = Field(default=True, primary_key=True)
    published_at: datetime = Field(default=datetime.utcnow(), nullable=False)


class BlogCreate(BlogBase): 
    pass
```

Can someone help me in understanding the problem and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module supplies classes/objects for manipulating dates. One of them is [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime). The `datetime` class also includes other class methods such as [`utcnow()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow), which you seem to be using in the example you provided.

Hence, you should instead use, for instance:

```py
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.utcnow()
```

**Note** how the `datetime` should be imported, that is:

```py
from datetime import datetime
```

`datetime` is basically a class inside a module that is also named `datetime`.

or, you could also do:

```py
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```