# Sentinel Values in Pydantic Model - Fastapi and Firestore

Tags: python, firebase, datetime, fastapi, pydantic

I am creating a backend with FastAPI and Firestore. I want to set one of my model fields `createdOn` as a `firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP`. In Python, it's stored as a `Sentinel`. However, what data type should I store in my Pydantic model for it to allow server timestamp.

My current model looks like this

```py
class NGO(BaseModel): 
    displayName: str = Field(..., example="Lorem Ipsum")
    tagline: str = Field(..., example="Lorem Ipsum")
    description: str = Field(..., example="Lorem Ipsum")
    status: str = Field(..., example="active")
    logoUrl: str = Field(..., example="https://www.thehindu.com/static/theme/default/base/img/branding/logo.png")
    bannerUrl: list = Field(..., example=["https://www.thehindu.com/static/theme/default/base/img/branding/logo.png"])
    contactName: str = Field(..., example="Lorem Ipsum")
    contactEmail: str = Field(..., example="abcd@gmail.com")
    contactNumber: str = Field(..., example="+91 1234567890")
    website: str = Field(..., example="https://www.thehindu.com")
    associatedMagazines: Optional[list] = Field(None, example=["abc123"])
    associatedProjects: Optional[list] = Field(None, example=["abc123"])
    createdBy: Optional[str] = Field(None, example="Lorem Ipsum")
    updatedBy: Optional[str] = Field(None, example="Lorem Ipsum")
    isFeatured: Optional[bool] = Field(None, example=False)
    publicRegistryId: Optional[str] = Field(None, example="abc123")
    createdOn: Optional[datetime] = Field(None, example=datetime.now())
```

and this is how I am declaring the NGO object

```py
ngo = NGO(
        displayName=displayName,
        description=description,
        tagline=tagline,
        status=status,
        logoUrl=logoUrl,
        bannerUrl=bannerUrl,
        contactName=contactName,
        contactEmail=contactEmail,
        contactNumber=contactNumber,
        website=website,
        updatedBy=updatedBy,
        isFeatured=isFeatured,
        publicRegistryId=publicRegistryId,
        createdOn=firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP,
    )
```

Currently, I am getting the following error.

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for NGO
createdOn
  invalid type; expected datetime, string, bytes, int or float (type=type_error)
```

How should I go about saving the firestore Server timestamp using the Pydantic model. Alternate suggestions to Pydantic are also accepted.

Comment: Did you try [setting custom data type](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/types/#custom-data-types)?

Comment: How can I do that for the sentinel data type?

Comment: One could likely use a `datetime` object, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74510906/17865804)

Answer (score 0):

Try using time instead of date time.

Example:

```
from time 
import time

createdOn: Optional[time] = Field(None, example=time())
```