# How to serialize post request with datetime in FastAPI

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, fastapi, datetime-format, pydantic

When I send a post request like this

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/v1/tasks/' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "title": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "deadline": "2023-06-25T15:31:44.204Z"
}'
```

I got **error** in logs

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.Error) <class 'asyncpg.exceptions.DataError'>: invalid input for query argument $3: '2023-06-25T15:31:44.204000+00:00' (expected a datetime.date or datetime.datetime instance, got 'str')
[SQL: INSERT INTO task (title, description, deadline) VALUES ($1::VARCHAR, $2::VARCHAR, $3::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE) RETURNING task.id]
[parameters: ('string', 'string', '2023-06-25T15:31:44.204000+00:00')]
```

My **model**

```
class Task(Base):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, index=True)
    title: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(40))
    description: Mapped[str]
    deadline: Mapped[datetime]
    performers = relationship(
        "User",
        secondary=association_table,
        back_populates="tasks",
    )
```

My **schema**

```
class TaskBase(BaseModel):
    title: str | None = None
    description: str | None = None
    deadline: datetime | None = None


class TaskCreate(TaskBase):
    title: str
    description: str
    # performers: list[UserBase] | None = None

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

My **CRUD** for **Task**

```
class CRUDTask(CRUDBase[Task, TaskCreate, TaskUpdate]):
    async def create(self, db: AsyncSession, obj_in: TaskCreate) -> Task:
        obj_in_data = jsonable_encoder(obj_in)
        # obj_in_data["deadline"] = datetime.strptime(
        #     obj_in_data["deadline"], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+00:00"
        # )
        db_obj = self.model(**obj_in_data)
        db.add(db_obj)
        await db.commit()
        await db.refresh(db_obj)
        return db_obj
```

I know that i should serialize datetime iso string and convert somehow, but don't know how to do it.
I tried to add json_encoder in class Config, but i got error "datetime Object not JSON serializable". When i added **commented lines** in **CRUD** it worked, but i think that's a not good practice.
Project: [Task-Tracker](https://github.com/yuwisasha/Task-Tracker)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74510906/17865804) asnwer your question?

Comment: No, i need to send random timestamp in post request like "2023-06-25 15:31:44" and save it in db.

Comment: Also, when i post request "2023-06-25 15:31:44" i have "2023-06-25**T**15:31:44" in my logs.

Answer (score 0):

Good Afternoon,

According to the specification for FastAPI. Responses and requests to the API will allow for Datetime to be ISO8601 strings. So potentially try this, which will also include the timezone which your error message appears to be complaining about:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/v1/tasks/' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "title": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "deadline": "2023-06-25T15:31:44+00:00"
}'
```

Comment: Same error. I'm so sorry, forgot to add CRUD in a question, i think it works wrong somewhere in it, it was working when i added _commented lines_, but i think that's a bad practice.